# Why does the Rambam change language?

Tags: halacha, rambam, grammar-dikduk, purim

In [Hilchos Megillah V'Chanukah](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02013.html#HtmpReportNum0094_L2), the Rambam writes in 2:15

> טו. כיצד חובת סעודה זו **שיאכל** בשר ויתקן סעודה נאה כפי אשר תמצא ידו,
>   **ושותה** יין עד שישתכר וירדם בשכרות

Why does the Rambam switch from future tense ("you should eat meat") to present tense ("and drink wine...")?

Comment: Some hold its a mitzvah to drink the whole day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Emek Beracha quotes from R' Yisroel Salanter that he held that this was an indication that the Rambam held the *mitzvah* is to be drunk, not to get drunk.  The Rambam held that getting drunk is not an *accomplishment* that you complete and then are done, but is a continual process throughout the day, and therefore if you sober up, you keep drinking.

Comment: "throughout the day" Shouldn't that be "throughout the Seudah"?

Comment: @DoubleAA could be, but that isn't the way he says it.  I assume he means it's all day whenever your seudah is, but that isn't the way he says it IIRC

Comment: @YeZ do you have the exact source, perhaps a hebrewbooks link?

Comment: @Bochur613 I have a pdf of it on my computer.  I could give you the page number.... p. 126

Comment: @Yez could you upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive and post the link here?